# Is there a good overview of conjugacy classes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

During the lecture of Algebra we had the topic „Conjugacy classes of $A_n$ and $S_n$“ and I somehow don‘t see through it. So I know that if we have a group acting on itself, then two elements are in the same conjgacy class if they are conjugate. Then we also had a statement saying that two elements are conjugate in $S_n$ if they have the same partition of $n$. But I really don‘t see through it, so I don‘t see where this can be used and how to work with. Does maybe someone know if there are some useful overview about this topic or are there some nice examples?

This would be very helpful.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If I read "somehow I don't see through it" I usually recommend to study conjugacy classes for groups of small order. With more examples done yourself the confidence grows quite a lot. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588777/conjugacy-classes-of-the-quaternion-group-q) for the conjugacy classes of the quaternion group. But of course also $A_n,S_n$ for small $n$, computed yourself is useful. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118447/how-do-i-find-the-conjugacy-classes-of-a-4?rq=1).

Comment: "Does maybe someone know if there are some useful overview about this topic or are there some nice examples?" Yes, there are several nice overviews. A good start is the overview of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the case first. Suppose we have a $i$-cycle $(a_1\; \cdots\;a_i)$ of $S_n$ and an arbitrary permutation $\sigma \in S_n$. Then conjugating $(a_1 \; \cdots \; a_i)$ by $\sigma$ gives
$$\sigma \circ (a_1 \; \cdots \; a_i) \circ \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1) \; \cdots \; \sigma(a_i))$$
(I will leave the verification to you; it is ruotine.) For the general case, we simply recall that every permutation can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles. Hence, we can see quickly that conjugating a permutation preserves its cycle type (which corresponds naturally to a partition of $n$)

Comment: "Does maybe someone know if there are some useful overview about this topic or are there some nice examples?" For me it seems the question is not only about $S_n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so we only looked at this topic in a very fast way, i.e. we only considered conjugacy classes for the symmetric and alternating group

Comment: Wave, that is certainly not enough. Some more examples are good. Like for a foreign language, only looking at adjectives and not at verbs ... OK, bad comparison...

Comment: Sure I understand you and I totally agree. So where would you recommend to start.

Comment: @Ray is it correct that one can check your given equation showing the following: $$\left(\sigma \circ (a_1 \; \cdots \; a_i) \circ \sigma^{-1}\right)(\sigma(a_n))= \sigma(a_{n+1})$$ and since this holds forall $1\leq n\leq i$ we have the equation

Comment: @Wave Yep, but I would say that you also need to check that everything not of the form $\sigma(a_j)$ is fixed by the conjugate

Comment: @Ray okey so I mean on the right it is clear that if we have something not of the form $\sigma(a_j)$ then this is fixed. Now we only need to look at the left hand side right? So if I understood this correclty I need to compute $$\left(\sigma \circ (a_1 \; \cdots \; a_i) \circ \sigma^{-1}\right)(a_j)= \left(\sigma \circ (a_1 \; \cdots \; a_i)\right) \sigma^{-1}(a_j)$$ but then we see that $(a_1 \; \cdots \; a_i)$ fixes $\sigma^{-1}(a_j)$ an thus the whole left hand side fixes everything not of the form $\sigma(a_j)$ right

Comment: Conjugation in the symmetric group amounts to relabeling the points in the cycles according to the conjugating permutation. In the alternating group, it amounts to relabeling the points in the cycles by a permutation that is itself an even permutation.